# Sentence VAE Loss Layer Implementation On Keras Giving Issues

Tags: keras, nlp, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder, seq2seq

So I've been implementing the sentence VAE on TF-Keras (latest versions). The custom function below calculates the VAE loss from sparse categorical outputs.

```
def vae_loss(encoder_inputs, decoder_outputs):
     sen_loss = K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(encoder_inputs, decoder_outputs, from_logits=True)
     sen_loss = K.sum(sen_loss, axis=-1)
     kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.mean(1 + z_log_sigma - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_sigma))
     loss = K.mean(sen_loss + kl_loss)
     return loss

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=vae_loss)
model.fit([seq_in,seq_out],
          seq_lab,
          batch_size=batch_size, 
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=0.1)

#Seq_in shape = (no_of_samples, maxlen)
#Seq_out shape = (no_of_samples, maxlen)
#Seq_lab shape = (no_of_samples, maxlen, 1)
```

while attempting to train, it gave the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. 
This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, 
which is not supported. 
Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not 
register dispatching, 
preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the 
Functional Model.
```

I then disabled eager tensors to allow the use of computational graphs. However, it gave the error:

```
FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
(0) Failed precondition: Could not find variable 
training_6/Adam/embedding_16/embeddings/v. 
This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the 
variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status=Not found: 
Resource localhost/training_6/Adam/embedding_16/embeddings/v/N10tensorflow3VarE does 
not exist.
[[{{node training_6/Adam/Adam/update_embedding_16/embeddings/ReadVariableOp_3}}]]
[[_arg_keras_learning_phase_0_3/_722]]

(1) Failed precondition: Could not find variable 
training_6/Adam/embedding_16/embeddings/v. 
This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the 
variable is uninitialized. 
Debug info: container=localhost, status=Not found: Resource 
localhost/training_6/Adam/embedding_16/embeddings/v/N10tensorflow3VarE does not 
exist.
[[{{node training_6/Adam/Adam/update_embedding_16/embeddings/ReadVariableOp_3}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

The code to the model is this:

```
#################################### ENCODER LAYER ################################
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(maxlen, ))

# Encoder Embedding
enc_emb = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim,
                trainable=True)(encoder_inputs)

# Encoder LSTM
encoder_lstm3 = LSTM(latent_dim)
encoder_outputs = encoder_lstm3(enc_emb)


#################################### VAE Z LAYER ################################
z_mean = Dense(units=latent_dim)(encoder_outputs)
z_log_sigma = Dense(units=latent_dim)(encoder_outputs)

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim), mean=0., stddev=1.0)
    return z_mean + z_log_sigma * epsilon

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_sigma])

expandz_h = Dense(latent_dim)
z_exp_h = expandz_h(z)

expandz_c = Dense(latent_dim)
z_exp_c = expandz_c(z)


#################################### DECODER LAYER ################################
# Set up the decoder, using z layer outputs as the initial state
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(maxlen, ))

# Embedding layer
dec_emb = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, trainable=True)(decoder_inputs)

# Decoder LSTM
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True,
                return_state=True, dropout=0.4,
                recurrent_dropout=0.0)
(decoder_outputs, decoder_fwd_state, decoder_back_state) = \
decoder_lstm(dec_emb, initial_state=[z_exp_h, z_exp_c])

# Dense layer
decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.summary()
```

I believe the problem lies in the implementation of the loss_function in tf-keras but I could be wrong and would really appreciate guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but since I had the same problem when training a VAE, I'll still post my solution. What solved it was creating two individual loss functions, one for the kl_loss and one for the reconstruction loss. The kl_loss was then given z_mean and z_log_sigma as arguments, rather than encoder_inputs and decoder_outputs. Then I compiled my model with two loss functions. In your case this would mean

```
def sen_loss(encoder_inputs, decoder_outputs):
    sl = K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(encoder_inputs, ecoder_outputs, from_logits=True)
    return K.sum(sl, axis=-1)

def kl_loss(z_mean, z_log_sigma):
    return - 0.5 * K.mean(1 + z_log_sigma - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_sigma))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=[sen_loss, kl_loss], loss_weights=[1.,1.])
```